# Foundation Orbit Off Center on Safari MAC OS X

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I currently have a foundation orbit running with the following:

```
     <ul data-orbit>

          <li> 
            <img class="image1" src="../templates/img/image1.jpg" style="width: 100%;       height: 691px; margin: 0 auto;"/>   
          </li>
          <li>
             <img class="image2" src="../templates/img/image2.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 691px; margin: 0 auto;"/>   
        </li>
         <li>
            <img class="image3" src="../templates/img/image3.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 691px; margin: 0 auto;"/>   
        </li>
     </ul>
```

On Windows, the browsers check out fine. However, on the Mac OS X Safari, it is displaying the next list item image instead of displaying the whole 100% width.

I'm guessing that it has something to do with the actual width and height of the images being displayed not being all the same size...?

I would like to try to fix this minor issue without having to cut out all the images to be the same width and height since it's only tailored for only the mac safari.

I tried to change the foundation.orbit.js to change 
$slides.css (around line 340) to read jquery.safari and tried altering its width, but it just ends up stretching the image on safari.

Thank you!

Comment: Need a jsfiddle or some other reduced test case.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in the MAC OS X, the clientWidth is 1px shorter than what it should be (1038 instead of 1039px).

By forcing the width to be `1039px !important` for the CSS on the safari browser, it took care of the issue.
I don't know why the width is forced to be 1px shorter than what it is, but whatever.